# Struggling to import Oracle tables via Excel Power Pivot

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, powerpivot, oracle-11g

I have an issue where i'm trying to pull some data from an Oracle table via Excel Power Pivot.  To connect to Oracle, i used Table Import Wizard in Power Pivot and entered all the required info (Server Name, User Name, Password).  The provider i chose is "Oracle Provider for OLE DB".  I tested the connection to Oracle and it works.

Next step in the Import Wizard is to view the tables that are available to pull.  I select the table, preview it and apply some filters (which i can see the data), then i press "Finish" to commit to pulling the data. The next step provides a status of the import which i get one of the below error messages:

1. OLE DB or ODBC error: ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied
2. Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Out of the 1000 times i tried to pull Oracle data using Power Pivot, i was able to see Power Pivot importing rows of data once but i stopped it before it was able to finish.

I know i am able to connect to Oracle because I can see the available tables in Power Pivot as well as my other applications (Excel, Access, TOAD) can pull this data so I know I don't have connections issues.  I know i'm able to pull the data in Power Pivot as i was able to see it import the data partially.  What the heck is causing the import in Power Pivot to fail?

I'm using Excel 2016 and the Oracle version is Oracle Database 11g.

Please let me know if you need further info or clarification.  Much thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

The newer and better way to achieve this is to start from the Excel Data ribbon and use **Get Data / From Database / From Oracle Database**.  After entering your connection and credential info, you can use the Navigator to pick your tables or views.  At the bottom of the Navigator pane, pick **Load / Load To...** and choose **Only create connection** and also **Add this data to the Data Model**.

The end result is superficially the same, but you can now take advantage of the Query Editor to filter or shape your data on the way into the model, and blend in data from other sources.  More importantly, the functionality for handling connections and credentials is very reliable (it's shared with Power BI).

Comment: Mike.. thanks for your reply!  I tried your method but i got an error message as soon as i select "From Oracle Database".  The error message reads: The recommended provider ('Oracle.DataAccess.Client') is not installed.  You can continue with your current provider, however it has been deprecated and may not work properly.  Upon checking the Oracle website, it seems like i need to install " 32-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio".  Hopefully installing this will resolve my data retrieval issue.

Comment: I think that is actually a warning message and you can continue as is. Oracle client installs are a pit of despair ...

Comment: Argh.. Getting the same error message (DataSource.Error: The provider being used is deprecated: 'Unsupported Oracle data type 101 encountered.'. https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=272376) when using the power query method.  Clicking on the hyperlink brings me to the Microsoft site suggesting ODAC should be installed.  I need to ask my IT department to assist in installing this.  I'll provide an update later to see if installing this will resolve my issue.  This shouldn't be this difficult :(